# Array and AJAX returning messages after ajax

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I have my AJAX working and I can INSERT new data in the database. Basically I can not get an array to echo back into my page. I was wondering, do I need a separate AJAX to get the information from my first AJAX and will it work? Here is my code:

```
<?
$msg = array ("MSG1"=>"Error","MSG2"=>"Registered");
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    echo $msg['MSG1'];
}
?>

<script> 
function Registration(){
    var values = {};
    values['register'] = '';
    $.ajax({
        'url' : '',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : values,            
        success : function(data){
        }
    }) 
}
</script>
```

How can I get my Array to echo back from AJAX?

Comment: Try actually doing something with `data`

Comment: Dahh I was just wondering....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```
formData = {
    register: register
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://localhost/register.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //success handler
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

about your '**Array to echo back from AJAX**', you need to setup if else condition in your `'http://localhost/register.php'` . Let say if condition A, `"MSG1"=>"Error"`. If condition B, `"MSG2"=>"Registered"`.

Please refer to this site for your reference.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/